# Find the mean and standard deviation of all values in a data frame

Tags: r, statistics, average, variance, standard-deviation

I have a set of data frames each with different column names, e.g. `frameOne` looks like

```
   Q2  Q6  Q9
1   1   0   0
2   0   1   1
...
N   1   1   0
```

and `frameTwo` is

```
   Q1  Q5  Q9 Q22
1   1   1   0   1
2   1   0   1   0
...
N   1   1   1   0
```

How would I calculate the mean and standard deviation of the *entire frame* without explicitly stating the column names?

Comment: Column or object names?

Comment: Your data is binary? Does mean make any sense for it?

Comment: Yeah, it does make sense. They are correct/incorrect responses to questions, so the mean gives overall ability to answer this subset of questions.

Comment: So you need use another formula to standard deviation. I've edited @RomanLuštrik's answer with the correct one (`sqrt(prod(prop.table(table(st))))`)

Comment: Why can't I use `sd()`?

Comment: @Rcoster I don't see the edit?

Comment: @Rcoster Ah, I see it was rejected (with conflicting reasons).

Comment: @fophillips because sd() is for numeric data, not binary.

Comment: @Rcoster does this derive from the Bernoulli distribution variance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your answer, I'm guessing you're after this.

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(9), ncol = 3))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(9), ncol = 3))
df3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(9), ncol = 3))
df4 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(9), ncol = 3))

my.objs <- ls(pattern = "df")

sapply(my.objs, FUN = function(x) {
  st <- as.vector(as.matrix(get(x)))
  data.frame(mean = mean(st), sd = sd(st))
})

     df1       df2       df3       df4      
mean 0.4967452 0.4426861 0.5198141 0.3460732
sd   0.2533854 0.2179547 0.3106693 0.3179838
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work as in your example `dfx` are matrices not data frames: `str(df1): num [1:3, 1:3] 0.2384 0.733 0.0262 0.9102 0.5883 ...`. If I use `data.matrix()` in place of `get()`, this works.

Comment: @fophillips what about now?